# java: how to know the repeated word in a string?

Tags: java, string

would you please let me know if there is a way(java) to know the reapeated word in a string? example: 
check the repeated word in this 
string "**hihihi**" in this case the reapeated word is "**hi**".

string "**hellohellohellohello**"in this case the reapeated word is "**hello**".

string "**feefee**" in this case the reapeated word is "**fee**".

string "**AAAAAAAAAAAA**" in this case the reapeated word is "**A**".

knowng that the repeated word consist of **1 to 6** characters.

Best Regards, Maya

Comment: So the string consists of nothing but the repeated word?

Comment: Maybe this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: Is this your homework ????

Comment: @saman Why does that make any difference?

Comment: @takendarkk Because we won't do homework for other people, especially if they appear to haven't tried anything themselves

Comment: I agree they should make effort, but you make it sound like if you are working on school work then you can't be here which just isn't true. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @maya please narrow down the question with the following details i) do you need to find the maximum length word which is repeated multiple times? or ii) do you need to find a word which is repeated maximum number of times? iii) also please add code snippet of what you have tried so far iv) what problem you face during you implementation?  - so that it would help fellow stack developers here to help you..

Comment: @saman this is not a home work. am trying to solve a big problem and this is part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is simple:

- See if the first character is repeated throughout the string
- See if the first two characters are repeated throughout the string
- See if the first three characters are repeated throughout the string
- See if the first four characters are repeated throughout the string
- See if the first five characters are repeated throughout the string
- See if the first six characters are repeated throughout the string

To see if character `i` is a repeated character from the initial `k` characters in a word, use

```
if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i%k))
```

where `k` is the length of the word that you are checking. If all letters pass this test for a particular `k`, and the length of the string is divisible by `k` (i.e. `s.length() % k == 0`) then the word `s` is composed of repeated words of length `k`.

Comment: As I say in my answer, it may be more efficient to look for six-character repeats first followed by the shorter repeats.

Comment: @rossum Correctness comes before efficiency: `AAAAAAAAAAAA` is a word where `A` is repeated 12 times, but if you check length of `6` first, you'd find that it is composed of two six-letter words `AAAAAA`.

Comment: thank you for your replies.yes, in the case of (AAAAAAAAAAAA) when A is repeated 12 times, the repeated word should be A not  six-letter words AAAAAA, as  dasblinkenlight said

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Java function to do this so you will have to write your own program.

Start by looking at your example "hellohellohellohello".  The word "hello" is repeated, so are the words "hell", "ello", "hel" etc.  This has the feel of a question in a course, so check with your instructor that only the longest word is required.

Start by finding the longest repeated word, which will be a maximum of six characters.  Try for a six character repeated word.  If there isn't one, then look for a five character repeated word and so on down to a one character repeated word.  By starting with the longest you will avoid wasting time finding shorter words (if they are not needed).  If your instructor wants all words, then the order you find them does not matter.

That implies that you need to write a method to find an n-character repeated word in a string, where n is a parameter you pass into the method.  Concentrate on writing that method first.  Ask here again if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem. But this isn't general.

```
public class MaxSubString {
    private final static int MAX_SUB_STRING_LENGTH = 6;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(maxSubString("hellohellohello")); // result is hello
        System.out.println(maxSubString("helhelhel")); // result is hel
        System.out.println(maxSubString("AAAAAAAAAAAAA")); // result is A
        System.out.println(maxSubString("hehehehehehe")); // result is he
    }

    public static String maxSubString(String inputString){
        int maxSubStringLength = calculateMaxSubStringLength( inputString);
        return inputString.substring(0,maxSubStringLength);
    }

    public static int calculateMaxSubStringLength(String inputString) {
        int result = -1;
        for(int i= MAX_SUB_STRING_LENGTH ; i>0 ; i--){
            if(inputString.length() < i *2)
                continue;
            if (inputString.substring(0,i).equals(inputString.substring(i , 2*i)))
            result = i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```